# jQuery Mobile Orientation Change Solutions

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, orientation, landscape, portrait

I'm developing a jQuery Mobile app. There's a ton of dynamically generated CSS to it and thus far I've been developing everything for the portrait orientation. The obvious problem is that when I tilt my device it looks very bad. I don't need to have a landscape view for the app but I'm not opposed to it either. Can anyone suggest an easiest solution the options being either a landscape view or somehow locking the app in portrait mode?

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to check orientation..
Firstly
1)

```
$(window).bind("orientationchange", function(evt){
                   alert(evt.orientation);
/*do what you want.*/
                   });
```

secondly using css you can check using min-width .I am using iPad then i check for 768 and 1024 .Do the things

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    #realTimeContents {
   overflow-y:auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  position: relative;
  height:850px 

}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
    #realTimeContents {
   overflow-y:auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  position: relative;
  height:600px 

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you possibly elaborate on implementation? I pasted the code into a style tag and it didn't do anything. Also is that the correct syntax?

Comment: Thank you for the update. I've managed to successfully detect the orientation change using the first javascript message you gave, but I'm not able to adjust the css for the orientation change.

Comment: But CSS is another way .I am always using css .Ok please tick the answer so that other's also use this answer.

Comment: I haven't been able to implement a solution from your answer. My question is how to adjust for orientation change not how to detect it.